# Why the state in benchmark didn't reset?

Tags: benchmark

```
# steps to reproduce
git clone https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-common
cd darwinia-common
git checkout xavier/bench
cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks
target/release/drml benchmark --header .maintain/lincense-header --execution native --heap-pages 4096 --chain pangolin-dev --output node/runtime/pangolin/src/weights/ --extrinsic 'claim_bounty' --pallet 'pallet_bounties'

# result                     
2022-08-11 16:51:39 `pallet_timestamp::UnixTime::now` is called at genesis, invalid value returned: 0    
2022-08-11 16:51:39 [0]  generated 1 npos voters, 1 from validators and 0 nominators    
2022-08-11 16:51:39 [0]  generated 1 npos voters, 1 from validators and 0 nominators    
2022-08-11 16:51:39 [0]  new validator set of size 1 has been processed for era 1    
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:77] &pot_account = 6d6f646c64612f74727372790000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (5EYCAe5g...)
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:80] &value = 1000000000
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:150] frame_system::Pallet::<T>::block_number() = 0
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:155] &bounty_id = 0
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:157] &curator = 4a12a3ac483a9db634e75b6358a8fdc1ca6d3b784566cd4e0c092b0f910c5b71 (5DjpwLaa...)
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:162] &beneficiary = MultiAddress::Id(
    7733dba55f14729038399c06e59481896b0a1531fbb807f1b77a712e8e3e63cb (5EkzxfK9...),
)
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:77] &pot_account = 6d6f646c64612f74727372790000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (5EYCAe5g...)
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:80] &value = 1000000000
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:150] frame_system::Pallet::<T>::block_number() = 0
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:155] &bounty_id = 0
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:157] &curator = 4a12a3ac483a9db634e75b6358a8fdc1ca6d3b784566cd4e0c092b0f910c5b71 (5DjpwLaa...)
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:162] &beneficiary = MultiAddress::Id(
    7733dba55f14729038399c06e59481896b0a1531fbb807f1b77a712e8e3e63cb (5EkzxfK9...),
)
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:77] &pot_account = 6d6f646c64612f74727372790000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (5EYCAe5g...)
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:80] &value = 1000000000
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:150] frame_system::Pallet::<T>::block_number() = 57600
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:155] &bounty_id = 1
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:157] &curator = 4a12a3ac483a9db634e75b6358a8fdc1ca6d3b784566cd4e0c092b0f910c5b71 (5DjpwLaa...)
[/root/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-a7fa553ead635512/a7bbfa3/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs:162] &beneficiary = MultiAddress::Id(
    7733dba55f14729038399c06e59481896b0a1531fbb807f1b77a712e8e3e63cb (5EkzxfK9...),
)
Error: Input("Premature")
```

I notice block number 57600 is `BountyDepositPayoutDelay`. And I think it was changed by this [line](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs#L159).

But why? Every new round should be started with a branch new state. Also, why the first two round works but failed at the third round?

If I run the pallet-bounties's benchmark in Polkadot. It works as expected. Always starting from block number 0.

Custom logs are defined [here](https://github.com/darwinia-network/substrate/blob/xavier/debug/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs).

It looks like this [line](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a1a9b475c354d873f91135ed5fa028ac9ef6a2c4/frame/benchmarking/src/lib.rs#L1113) doesn't work.

Comment: Why did you replace the `T::BountyDepositPayoutDelay::get() + 1u32.into()` with `T::BountyDepositPayoutDelay::get()`? IIUC it should throw a `Premature` error like you are getting.

Comment: I didn't modify anything. Just use the paritytech/substrate as my dep directly. Why I got different result?

Comment: Maybe it was a bug-fix in between, but you can see that [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6cd7ac7bd1e9da914adb7c8066d759f0a2d3849f/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs#L159) line is now missing the +1 [here](https://github.com/darwinia-network/substrate/blob/bde1feac9c491f3ffc3c74f8a3f7de97ef8acd3e/frame/bounties/src/benchmarking.rs#L165).

Comment: I add one now but still got this error. But the question is why it doesn't reset the DB. Even +100 to it, LOL.

Comment: Huh, there is actually an issue with resetting the State in case the Extrinsic errors. I am currently fixing it but for that to work you would have to update your Substrate.

Comment: My code base is at the same commit as polkadot-0.9.13. But it looks like everything works well on polkadot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because my ED is too small. Then it fails somewhere.

> Huh, there is actually an issue with resetting the State in case the Extrinsic errors. I am currently fixing it but for that to work you would have to update your Substrate. –
> Oliver Tale-Yazdi

And it relate to that bug. So the state can not be reset. Substrate&Polkadot's ED is big enough so no error, and they are able to reset DB correctly.

Fixed [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12025).